# Websockets - is additional framing required?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I've implemented messaging over TCP/UDP sockets before and had to implement my own framing between the app and the transport.  Is this required when using Websockets?  Specifically referring to the package available on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

i.e. assuming the following method:

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

If I send a message from the other end with some arbitrarily large amount of data, will this method fire once or multiple times with many segments that I then have to reconstruct into a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webSocket protocol has its own framing and the underlying webSocket library will handle all that for you.  You do not have to worry about the framing.  The method you show will fire once for each message sent, no matter how large it is (up to whatever the practical message size limit is in any given limitation).

Aside from memory limitations, the particular server-side implementation you reference, appears [to check incoming payloads](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/fe44ff81cc414495f19416847ce658cbea079d06/lib/Receiver.js#L274) for a size larger than 2^53 - 1 bytes and return an error if found.

It also appears to have a [default maxPayload of 100MB](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/fe44ff81cc414495f19416847ce658cbea079d06/lib/WebSocketServer.js#L49) that can be configured to be larger if you desire.